# How to prove that a trigonometric function is positive in an interval?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, graphing-functions

How can I prove that the function $f(x)=\sin(x)-x\cos(x)$ is positive in the interval $]0,π]$?

Comment: Hint. Note that $f'(x)=x\sin(x)>0$ in $[0,\pi]$

Comment: In addition to @RobertZ, comment, you can point out that the derivative, $x \sin{x}$ is the product to two positive numbers in this interval, so it's clear that the derivative is positive. After that it's only a matter of pointing out that $f(0)=0$ and you're all set.

Comment: Do you know $\tan x>x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$f(x)=\sin x-x\cos x\implies f(0)=0,\, f(\pi)=\pi$$

and since $\sin x > 0$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$

$$f'(x)=x\sin x>0$$

thus $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on that interval and $f(x)>0$.